# Pandas Group by id column and hourly datetime with missing hours

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with the following columns: 'Id', 'Date', and 'Number'. I need to group the data by Id and aggregate the Number hourly. Also, I need the hours with no data between the min and max datetimes of a Id to be present.

So for the toy dataset:

```py
Id    Date                    Number
1     01-01-2022 00:00:00     1
1     01-01-2022 00:25:00     3
1     01-01-2022 01:00:10     1
2     01-01-2022 00:00:01     4
2     01-01-2022 03:01:01     2
```

I would get:

```py
Id    Date                    Number
1     01-01-2022 00:00:00     4
1     01-01-2022 01:00:00     1
2     01-01-2022 00:00:00     4
2     01-01-2022 01:00:00     NaN
2     01-01-2022 02:00:00     NaN
2     01-01-2022 03:00:00     2
```

I tried it with groupby and Grouper (as shown below), but it results in missing hours.

```py
agg = {'Number': 'sum'} #example
data = data.groupby(['Id', pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='1H')]).agg(agg)
```

It seems simple, but I cannot get it to work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `.groupby().resample()` if you set the date as the index:

```
df.set_index('Date').groupby('Id').resample('1h')['Number'].sum()
```

```
Id  Date               
1   2022-01-01 00:00:00    4
    2022-01-01 01:00:00    1
2   2022-01-01 00:00:00    4
    2022-01-01 01:00:00    0
    2022-01-01 02:00:00    0
    2022-01-01 03:00:00    2
Name: Number, dtype: int64
```

Comment: It works correctly at the indexes, but it fills number with 0. Anyway to have it as NaN? There are true zeros in the real dataset and I'd like to back fill the new rows.

Comment: I have solved it. I added a new column before the resample and used it to select only the new rows.